# Percentage change according to input

Tags: python, input, output, percentage, difference

Is there any way to write a code
That whenever the input is different the percentage changes
So for example
If input is 100 the percentage is 50/50
If input if 90 the percentage is 60/40
If input is 80 the percentage is 70/30
And so on?
Thank You
With respect Umer Selmani

Comment: Well...what have you tried?

Comment: Actually i dont have any idea at all, and as the % sign is remainder in python i wanted to have some ideas from you guys, that is there any way how to code something with percetange

Comment: Well...try something first!

Comment: Try working out the algebra first, then turning that into code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try...

```
userin = int(input())
x = 100 - userin
one = str(50 + x) 
two = str(50 - x) 
print(one + "/" + two)
```

I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to accomplish with this, but this seems to kind of work.
Shorter:

```
userin = int(input())
x = 100 - userin
print(str(50+x) + "/" + str(50-x))
```

Comment: An attack with magnitude M will be successful with a chance of (100-M)%. That is, higher
magnitude means higher risk of missing it. For instance, if M is 30, the chance of succeeding would
be 70%, whereas, if M is 10, the chance of succeeding would be 90%. If an attack with magnitude 
3 | P a g e
M is successful, the attacked hero’s health points will decrease by M. If the user writes more than
50 or less than 1, the game should warn the player, and re-ask for another attack magnitude as
below.
this is the original question

Comment: Ahhh... I understand now.